# RegEx: Split String at Capitalized Letters and Non-capitalized letters to Create Small Cap Fonts

Tags: .net, regex, split

So i've purposefully stayed away from RegEx as just looking at it kills me...ugh. But now I need it and could really use some help to do this in .NET (C# or VB.NET). I need to split a string based on capitalization or lack thereof. For example:

> **I'm not upPercase**
>
> 1. "I"
> 2. "'m not up"
> 3. "P"
> 4. "ercase"

or

> **FBI Agent Winters**
>
> 1. "FBI A"
> 2. "gent "
> 3. "W"
> 4. "inters"

The reason I'm doing this is to manually create small caps, in which non-capitalized strings will be sent to uppercase and their font size made 80% of the original font size. Appreciate any help that could be provided here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this regular expression should work
`/([A-Z ]*)([^A-Z]*)/`

It makes those splits on that data according to 
[rubular.com](http://rubular.com)

Comment: Great site, I've bookmarked that one for future reference. I slightly changed your pattern and it works like a charm: `/([A-Z]+)([^A-Z]+)/`

Comment: Just to have it said, this RE assumes, of course, that no input in non-latin scripts is entered. It completely ignores, e.g., Greek and Korean.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like you just need to match anything that's not an uppercase letter.  For example:

```
input = Regex.Replace(input, @"[^A-Z]+", ToSmallCaps);
```

...where `ToSmallCaps` is a [MatchEvaluator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator.aspx) delegate that converts the matched text to small caps, however it is you're doing that.  For example:

```
static string ToSmallCaps(Match m)
{
  return String.Format(@"<span style=""whatever"">{0}</span>", m.Value);
}
```

EDIT: A more Unicode-friendly version regex would be `@"[^\p{Lu}\p{Lt}]+"`, which matches one or more of anything other than an uppercase or titlecase letter, in any language.

Comment: Thanks Alan. I need to match both anything that is one or more capital letters and anyone or more characters that are not capitals.

Answer (score 2):

Although Alan's answer will probably solve your problem, for completeness' sake, I'm posting a regex that returns both the uppercase and the lowercase parts as matches, like in your example.

ANSI:

```
Regex.Matches("I'm not upPercase", @"[^a-z]+|[^A-Z]+");
```

Unicode:

```
Regex.Matches("I'm not upPercase", @"[^\p{Ll}]+|[^\p{Lu}]+");
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is also can be achieved using assertions in regular expressions:

```
<?php
$str = 'TestMyFuncCall';
var_dump(preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/', $str, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "Test"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "My"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "Func"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "Call"
}
```

I'm sorry for PHP, no Visual Studio in the reach. But you can do pretty much the same in .NET I'm sure.